# Higher order singular value decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, svd

Can anyone  give a clear explanation with example of the [higher order singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition) (HOSVD). All the references are theoretical stuff. I would like to have a simple example.